# Intuition behind tight, dual and complementary frames

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, hilbert-spaces, intuition, signal-processing

> A finite sequence $(\phi_i)_{i=1}^M$ of vectors in a finite dimensional
>   Hilbertspace $\mathcal{H}$ (for simplicity $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ here) is a frame for $\mathcal{H}$, if it spans $\mathcal{H}$.

Can one give an intuitive, geometric view of the dual frame, the canonical tight frame and the complementary frame?
For example given some picture of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ how can one "see", if this frame is tight, and how the associated other frames look like?

*(I know all the mathematical definitions, equivalent formulations and proofs regarding frames and can also apply them, but I am lacking the intuition and the geometric image)*